# Чёрный экран при установке Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Добрый день

Сегодня столкнулся с проблемой установки Ubuntu 13.04

При первой попытке просмотра системы все прошло удачно, мне все понравилось и я решил ее себе установить. Перезагрузил компьютер, почистил HDD, сбросил BIOS на дефолт, ну и преступил к установке Ubuntu. Но уже при следующих попытках выскакивал выскакивал черный экран после загрузки логово данной ОС. nomodeset не помагает, или я не верно его ввожу.

Расскажите пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего - дефолтные настройки BIOS не есть оптимальные. Я бы рекомендовал поиграться с ними...

Кстати, ни чистить винт, ни сбрасывать BIOS было ну совершенно не обязательно... Но это так, лирика))

UP

Да, и еще... До выбора языка у Вас не дошло? Или, может быть, дошло до выбора "установить/попробовать/бла-бла-бла"? Больше подробностей!..

Comment: У меня вообще страшная установка, у меня прежде нужно выбрать Установить или Просмотреть, только потом будет язык и все дела. Но как только я выбираю какое то меню, то загружается лого убунты, ну а потом черный экран.

Comment: Вариант типа "Проверить диск а целостность" есть? Если есть - пробовать. Как вариант - попробовать другой дистрибутив. Например - 12.04 LTS.Но предварительно - разобраться с BIOS + покурить маны, возможно есть какие-то особенности требований по настройкам на вашем железе.